# 406 not acceptable in Django Rest Swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

All my Django Rest Api use Accept parameter = application/hal+json but when I try to integrate Django Rest Swagger on top of these Api's it start giving me 406 unacceptable because by default DRS takes application/json as accept parameter.

What is the best way to provide application/hal+json in Django Rest Swagger.  I tried changing some settings using path for every api and also change swagger-ui.js.

Comment: found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Removing The default renderer `'drf_hal_json.renderers.JsonHalRenderer'`
solved my problem. We where not using that renderer anyway.

```
DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES=(
-    'drf_hal_json.renderers.JsonHalRenderer',
     'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
     'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer'
 ),
```

The swagger-ui did not get the expected json response.